# Least squares kernel trick

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, least-squares

I was reading this about least squares and came cross the following claim.

https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_ols_kernels.html

$\displaystyle\min_w : |X^Tw - y|_2^2 + \lambda |w|_2^2 $ solution of this least squares is in $\operatorname{span}(X)$, I am trying to understand the proof for this.

I found following article which states that any vector can be expressed as sum of orthogonal vectors and so we can choose $Xv$ which is in the $\operatorname{span}(X)$ and $r$ orthogonal vector to range of $x$ to represent $w$.

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~russell/classes/cs194/f11/lectures/CS194%20Fall%202011%20Lecture%2007.pdf

But I don't understand how this proves optimal $w$ being in $\operatorname{span}(X)$.

Can you anyone help me in proving this.

Comment: write $w = v+u$ where $v \in span(X), u  \not \in span(X)$, so that $X^T w = X^T(v+u) = X^T v$, and hence it is always better to choose $u = 0$ since it will reduce $\|v+u\|^2$ without changing $\|X^T (v+u)-y\|^2$

Comment: I forgot to mention that $v,u$ lie in two different subspace, so that $\|v+u\|^2 = \|v\|^2+\|u\|^2$

Comment: I think $u \notin span(X)$ does not mean $X^Tu = 0$

Comment: By $\operatorname{span}(X)$, do you mean the span of the set of _columns_ of $X$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy if $X$ is not square, it has to be the columns, and if it is the rows, then it is not true anymore that the optimum  is in $span(X)$. @ Kumaran here it is what I meant : $v \in span(X)$, $u \in span(X)^\perp$ so that $X^T u = 0$

Comment: @user1952009, Thanks.  That proves it.

Comment: @reuns, why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @reuns:

Write $ w = v + u $ where $ v \in \operatorname{span} \left( x \right) $, $ u \notin \operatorname{span} \left( x \right) $, namely $ \left\| v + u \right\|^{2} = \left\| v \right\|^{2} + \left\| u \right\|^{2} $.

Hence $ {X}^{T} w = {X}^{T} \left( v + u \right) = {X}^{T} c $. This suggests it is always best to choose $ u = 0 $ since it reduces $ \left\| v + u \right\|^{2} $ without changing $ \left\| {X}^{T} \left( u + v \right) - y \right\|^{2} $.